# Jquery watermark not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery watermark plugin its working properly in all browser but not in IE8.

In other browser the watermark text consider as blank but in IE8 the watermark text is not consider as blank so that related validation are not working in IE8

can any one tell me how to fix this bug or it is the bug in IE8,any solution?

Comment: No code, no answer... If I download and run the latest version from https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/ it just works in IE8...

Comment: if you left your textbox balnk with watermark and chek below code with both other browser and IE8 then you will get what I am trying to say and whats is the bug........... alert(document.getElementById("txtid").value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this plugin

http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/jquery.placeholder.js?0.7.0

```
$(function () { $(":input[placeholder]").placeholder();});

<input style="width:128px;" type="text" id="DFrom" value="" placeholder="Here is your water mark" />
```